# Как во втором DBGrid-е отобразить все записи, которые принадлежат выделенной строке в первом DBGrid-е?

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal, lazarus

В БД есть две таблицы:

```
1 - менеджеры (ид, имя)
2 - клиенты (ид, ид_менеджера, имя)
```

Каждый клиент закреплен за одним и только одним менеджером.

На форме два `DBGrid, первый отвечает за таблицу менеджеров, второй - за таблицу клиентов.

**Как во втором DBGrid-е отобразить все записи, которые принадлежат выделенной строке в первом DBGrid-е ?**

`DBGrid1` - Query1 - 'select имя from менеджеры'

`DBGrid2` - Query2 - 'select имя from клиенты where ид_менеджера = :ид_менеджера'

Я понимаю, как это сделать в принципе, но не понимаю, как сделать это при помощи DBGrid-ов.

Answer (score 2):

Можно через обработку события `CellClick` у первого `DBGrid`. Но это как-то некрасиво и требует пассов руками и ненужных, на мой вкус, действий.

Проще по-другому - через использование `MasterSource`, он для таких вот авто-действий и разрабатывался:

У вас на форме уже есть компоненты:

`TADOConnection`, `TADOTable` — 2 экземпляра, `TDBGrid` — 2 экземпляра, `TDataSource` — 2 экземпляра

Считаем, что все связи прописаны для 2х наборов `ADOTable1 - DataSource1 - DBGrid1` (менеджеры) и `ADOTable2 - DataSource2 - DBGrid2` (клиенты), `ADOConnection` к ним также привязан, а `Active` у `ADOTable1` установлен в **true**.

Теперь для `ADOTable2` свойство `MasterSource` устанавливаем в DataSource1 (вашу таблицу с менеджерами), а в свойстве `MasterFields` указываем связующие поля. Теперь также устанавливаете `Active` у `ADOTable2` в **true**, и всё должно заработать.

К сожалению, я далёк от компьютера с Delphi, показал бы с картинками :)